# How to use icons in jsTree?

Tags: asp.net, jstree

I have an ASP.NET app and use jsTree. 
It uses node icons from files in wwwroot folder.
I create a tree using hierarchy from database. 
The data passed via ajax method call as described in documentation.
It works ok.
The hierarchy contains icons for different node types too.
How to use node icons from database in my jsTree tree?

Answer (score 1):

The jsTree plugin needs an *url* or a *path* to the image of each node.

You can make the icons public on your web server or CDN and then store the icon url in your database.

Then return that *url* in your AJAX response as the **icon** value for every node.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanx, it is one of ways. How I can pass a blob value containing image  from the database?

Comment: That depends on your backend technology. Just find a method/library for your backend language/framework.